# Textmate 2 indentation with Python

Tags: textmate, textmate2

When I indent by tabbing "Tab" key, the tab is replaced by 4 spaces. Does anyone know how could I set it to normal?

Comment: Nooooo! You should be using spaces not tabs! http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the bottom of the editor window there is a menu for tab size, you can set the desired width there as well as turning on soft tabs which inserts spaces instead of tabs but treats them as tabs when editing. Your choice will be saved based on the active file type so make sure to set it when in a python file.